# Pass array to postgresql query - nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I seem to be having an issue passing an array to my query and using the `IN` condition, I can successfully get results back when I manually add each search term to the query

```
async function getFixtures() {
  let response;
  try {
    response = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM fixtures WHERE league_name IN ('Chinese Super League', 'Iran Pro League', 'English Premier League')");
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Error Occurred', e);
  }
    return response.rows;
}
```

When I try passing an array though I get no results back

```
async function getFixtures(leaguesArray) {
  let response;
  try {
    response = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM fixtures WHERE league_name IN ($1)", [leaguesArray]);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Error Occurred', e);
  }
    return response.rows;
}
```

When I log out `leaguesArray` it will return

```
['Chinese Super League', 'Iran Pro League', 'English Premier League']
```

So when it is passed to the query I think it is

```
[['Chinese Super League', 'Iran Pro League', 'English Premier League']]
```

Do I need to convert that initial array to a string?

I am obviously missing something here but unsure as to what

Thanks

Comment: Are You sure that `("SELECT * FROM fixtures WHERE league_name IN ($1)", [leaguesArray])` works? I mean - are You sure that it replace $1 with that array in the query?

Comment: Take a look at following [GitHub FAQ](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/FAQ#11-how-do-i-build-a-where-foo-in--query-to-find-rows-matching-an-array-of-values), I think that targets exactly your problem.

Comment: Thanks @RamizWachtler, all sorted, `= ANY ($1)`

Answer (score 20):

As the [docs](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/FAQ#11-how-do-i-build-a-where-foo-in--query-to-find-rows-matching-an-array-of-values) mention. I believe you use two approaches

Approach #1

```
async function getFixtures(leaguesArray) {
let response;
  try {
    response = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM fixtures WHERE league_name = ANY ($1)", [leaguesArray]));
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Error Occurred', e);
  }
return response.rows;
}
```

Approach #2

```
async function getFixtures(leaguesArray) {
let response;
const offset = 1;
const placeholders = leagueArray.map(function(name,i) { 
    return '$'+(i+offset); 
}).join(',');
  try {
    response = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM fixtures WHERE league_name IN (" + placeholders+")", leaguesArray));
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Error Occurred', e);
  }
return response.rows;
}
```

Comment: Approach #2 fails if `placeholders` length is 0.  Getting `WHERE league_name IN ()` throws `syntax error at or near ")"`